# Resistor that changes resistance with clock input

Tags: resistors, 555, button, astable

I am making a 555 a stable connected to a 4510 and 4511 and an led row. I need the led row to get faster and therefore the 555 astable to get faster, the more times a button is pushed. I am thinking a resistor that changes resistance with a clock input and a reset function but I am new to electronics so anything is appreciated! A video of the circuit so far is here: https:https://goo.gl/5luzl1, and data sheets for the 4510 (I can only post two links so no 4511 pinout) is here: https://goo.gl/1UMyLg. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: No schematic means no answer. I'm too lazy to look up what 4510 and 4511 are, provide links to their datasheets. I have plenty of ideas but no clue about what you're doing.

Comment: @FakeMoustache 4510 and 4511 are standard 4000-series CMOS ICs. See: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4510b.pdf http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4511b.pdf

Comment: @FakeMoustache The 4510 is a BCD up/down counter and the 4511 is a BCD to 7-seg display decoder. None of that makes sense to me regarding "LED row". And I don't know what "get faster" means, either, quantitatively.

Comment: A 555 astable is connected to the clock of a 4510, which is connected to a 4511, 9 of the outputs of which are connected to nine LEDs, and the other output is connected to reset. This means that the first LED comes on for a split second, then goes off at the same time as the next LED comes on. 'Faster' means that I want each LED to be on for less time, making the whole cycle shorter. This can be done by altering the resistance of the 555 astable resistors, but I want it to happen the more times that the button is pressed.

Comment: Have a look at [DS1804](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1804.pdf) ... Does not have a reset.

Answer (score 2):

There are 'digipots' which are designed for a simple up-button/down-button type of interface (rather than SPI or I2C).
Unfortunately the ones which pop up in a quick search are packaged in small SMD footprints, but you could probably 'dead-bug' them if you're careful.
[Digikey Search](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/data-acquisition-digital-potentiometers/2556350?k=digital+pot&k=&pkeyword=digital+pot&pv154=15&pv154=1096&pv154=1034&FV=1c0002%2C1c0003%2C1000001%2C1000002%2C268000f%2C268040a%2C268040b%2C268040c%2C2680448%2C1f140000%2Cfff40027%2Cfff801be&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)

Example:
[image: Example Puchbutton Digipot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analog multiplexer such as a 4051 to select one of 8 resistors using a 3-bit input that you can connect to a counter or whatever strikes your fancy.

If the resistances are relatively low then you might have to use a more expensive analog multiplexer, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking a resistor that changes resistance with a clock input
>   and a reset function

Your thinking is good, but how to convert that idea into a realizable circuit? Break it down into elementary functions. You will need:-

1. A **counter** with clock and reset inputs. If 10 steps are enough then a CD4510 would do the job, otherwise choose another IC which counts to the number of steps you want (eg. CD4024).
2. A method of **switching in different resistor values** from the outputs of your counter. One way to do that is with analog switches. The [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf) has 4 switches which can be controlled from the four Q outputs of a CD4510.

As the count increases you want the 555 capacitor charging time to decrease, so the individual resistances should be switched into the timing circuit in [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Parallel_circuits). Since the counter outputs are in binary, the resistors should be [binary weighted](http://www.allsyllabus.com/aj/note/ECE/LINEAR_ICs_and_APPLICATIONS/unit4/BINARY-WEIGHTED%20RESISTOR%20DAC.php), with eg. 100k switched in from Q1, 50k from Q2 etc., halving the resistance value for each 2^n counter output.

3. **Clock and Reset** pulses generated by push-buttons.

The reset circuit is obvious, just connect a push-button to VDD or GND (depending on whether the reset pulse should be high or low) with a pull up/down resistor to the opposite supply rail. To make the counter reset on power up, wire a small capacitor (eg. 100nF) across the push-button.

The clocking circuit is not so easy. mechanical switches [bounce](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J16/4). If you use a simple push-button with pull up/down resistor, the counter may advance several counts each time you push the button. So you need some kind of [debouncing circuit](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing-pt2.htm) that guarantees only one clock pulse per button press. An SR latch would be ideal, except that it requires a switch with contacts for both up and down positions. Alternatively you could use an RC circuit to filter out the glitches, and a gate with Schmitt trigger input (eg. CD4093) to square up the output.